# Center axis on bone head

Tags: bones

Until before the holidays, I was happily using a key combination that would center the rotation axis nicely on the bone head, setting it to “local” rotation.

But I have completely forgotten what key combo I was using. D’oh. And I have searched and searched to no avail!

Can anybody remind me what key combo sets the axis center on the bone head?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Press ALT + .
2. Select it in the menu:

[image]